# coffeeScript date from String dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: date, coffeescript

Here I have two inputs fields. One is join date, and another is end of probation date.

The requirement is: if the user enters 24/07/2013 in join date input field, then 6 months after that date should show in the end of probation date field.

I’ve tried something like this:

```
joinDate = $('#user_join_date')
joinDate.blur ->
  probationDate = new Date(joinDate.val())
  myVar = new Date(probationDate.setMonth probationDate.getMonth() + 6)
  $('#user_probation_end_date').val(myVar)
```

But I'm not getting the date properly. What I have to change here?

Comment: does this code take care of rolling over into the next year? July + 6 > December

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `Date` constructor with a string like "25/03/2013".

Here's the corrected version

```
joinDate = $('#user_join_date')
joinDate.blur ->
  regex=/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/
  m=regex.exec(joinDate.val())
  probationDate = new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1])
  myVar = new Date(probationDate.setMonth probationDate.getMonth() + 6)
  $('#user_probation_end_date').val(myVar)
```

I'm matching the string in your format, and then creating with the Date Constructor

> new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

From: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Here's a JSFIDDLE I made: http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/psD3J/

Comment: Do you need any more help ?

Comment: No I have read it from w3schools after you told me.
And now my concept is cleared.

So thanking you from my bottom heart!

Comment: The [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) are generally preferred over http://w3fools.com/ as reference materials.